# New transactions during a Sybase "dump database" command

Tags: t-sql, sybase, database-backups

I have a **Sybase 15.5** database which is backed up every night using the `DUMP DATABASE` command.  The process takes about 30 minutes.

What happens to the transactions that occur within those 30 minutes?  Are they included in the backup or ignored?

Comment: I'm intensely curious about this. I can find okay info on [SQL Anywhere](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbadmin/recovery-internals-backup.html) and [SQL Server](https://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Debunking-a-couple-of-myths-around-full-database-backups.aspx) (and [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/100490/what-happens-during-a-live-sql-server-backup)), but not ASE. I wish this were more clearly documented for all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Transactions during the dump are included, with the exception of any at the very end of the dump in "phase 3".

From the [System Administration Guide: Volume 2](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31644.1502/pdf/sag2.pdf), Chapter 11: Developing a Backup and Recovery Plan, *Making routine database dumps: dump database*:

> Users can continue to make
>   changes to the database while the dump takes place. This makes it
>   convenient to back up databases on a regular basis.
>
> `dump database` executes in three phases. A progress message informs you
>   when each phase completes. When the dump is finished, it reflects all
>   changes that were made during its execution, except for those initiated
>   during phase 3.

All the data and log pages are dumped including those that are updated during the dump. Here is an example output:

```
Aug  6 16:32:42 2012: Backup Server: 4.188.1.1: Database mydb: 371587246 kilobytes (100%) DUMPED.
Aug  6 16:33:34 2012: Backup Server: 3.43.1.1: Dump phase number 1 completed.
Aug  6 16:33:34 2012: Backup Server: 3.43.1.1: Dump phase number 2 completed.
Aug  6 16:33:34 2012: Backup Server: 3.43.1.1: Dump phase number 3 completed.
Aug  6 16:33:34 2012: Backup Server: 4.188.1.1: Database mydb: 373878392 kilobytes (100%) DUMPED.
Aug  6 16:33:34 2012: Backup Server: 3.42.1.1: DUMP is complete (database mydb).
```

See also: http://www.sybaseteam.com/dump-database-t-506.html

Comment: +1. I imagine this is correct since it is my understanding that SQL Server operates in much the same way. However, I'd love to see this in some official documentation or perhaps a blog post by a Sybase employee. Possible?

Comment: Don't the section in Sybooks that I mention and the sybaseteam link explain though - what's missing exactly?  Myself I find it a bit puzzling that Sybase docs mention phase 3 in relation to db dump (as opposed to transaction log dump,) but still it's clear that all data pages and all log pages, including updates during the dump, are written out.

Comment: Ah, I missed the reference to the admin guide.  I've put that in and quoted the relevant info.  Good find.  I'm still not totally sure how to find the exact moment of crossover, but that's possibly for another question.